# Single-spa - is there a way to show loader while switching between micro frontends?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, micro-frontend, single-spa

I am using single-spa for a project, it consists of one root-config and multiple vue micro-frontends, i need to show overlay from vuetify [overlay](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/overlays/), is there a way i can acheive from mount function??

root-config.js

```
import * as singleSpa from "single-spa";
let appUrl = ["/app1", "/app2"];

appUrl.forEach(url => {
  singleSpa.registerApplication({
    name: "@test" + url,
    app: () => System.import("@test" + url),
    activeWhen: [url],
  });
})
/* here need to set loader */
```

main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import singleSpaVue from 'single-spa-vue'

import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

const vueLifecycles = singleSpaVue({
  Vue,
  appOptions: {
    render (h) {
      return h(App, {
        props: {
          
        }
      })
    },
    router,
    vuetify
  }
})

export const bootstrap = [vueLifecycles.bootstrap,doneBootstrap]
export const mount = vueLifecycles.mount
export const unmount = vueLifecycles.unmount

function doneBootstrap() {
  /* here need to unset loader */
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

Comment: Sunsar, Can you please explain a bit details with your code, since it is a micro application, what the is current behaviour?, and what is the issues / expected , it'll be very helpful for us to solve your issue faster

Comment: @chans i need to show a loader untill app.js from an application loads